# Perl fetch file to particular location

Tags: perl

The script below fetches the source to ghc to a folder calling './incoming/ghc.tar.bz2'. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify a destination file rather than a destination directory (and slurping the download into a scalar just to dump it later seems inefficient). What is the preferred way to download a file to a given path rather than to the directory specified by a given path. I would like to avoid depending on a non-core module or downloading to a `tmp` directory just to move the file somewhere else if at all possible.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

my $ff = File::Fetch->new(
    uri => 'http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/ghc-7.10.2-src.tar.bz2');

my $where = $ff->fetch(to => './incoming/ghc.tar.bz2');
```

Comment: You don't have to download to a temp directory and move the file. You could store it in your actual destination directory and `rename` it. Or use [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP), which is more or less the canonical way to handle network requests in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rename the file after it has been fetched. The automatic modification of the file name is unnecessary, but I threw it in anyways.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;
use File::Fetch;

my $dir = './incoming';

my $ff = File::Fetch->new(
    uri => 'http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/ghc-7.10.2-src.tar.bz2'
);

my $where = $ff->fetch(to => $dir);
my $fname = basename($where);

rename $where, "$dir/$fname";
```

Comment: A previous edit had me using `File::Copy` (http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html), but `rename` does the same thing as `File::Copy::move`, and it doesn't require another loaded module (although `File::Copy` is core)

Comment: It would be better to use File::Basename or File::Spec (both of which are core modules) to split the path.

Comment: Very good point. I'll fix it when I'm home unless you're inclined ;)

Comment: So my original motivation for asking was I don't want to clobber whatever file happened to be at the old location, and I figured the easiest way to accomplish that when I go back and make the script a little more resilient is to have control over the name of the file. Is the right approach to create a new directory for the file since you don't control its name and File::Fetch won't bother to append numbers for disambiguation?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet The right approach would be to use File::Temp to create a temporary directory, or LWP as I suggested in my other comment. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33796067/82262) for a solution using File::Temp.

Comment: @Gregory Or you could `use File::Copy;` and do your own "versioning" by copying before (or instead of) renaming. I'd suggest just appending a .timestamp: `copy($where,$where.".".`date +%F-%T`);`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just post-moving the file?:

```
...
my $where = $ff->fetch(to => './incoming');

system("mv", $where, "./incoming/ghc.tar.bz2");
```

Or, as stevieb notes, a better alternative is the builtin move:

```
...
my $where = $ff->fetch(to => './incoming');

rename $where, "./incoming/ghc.tar.bz2";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Fetch;
use File::Temp qw(tempdir);

my $dir = '/Users/matt/Desktop';
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => 'http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/ghc-7.10.2-src.tar.bz2');
my $where = $ff->fetch(to => tempdir(CLEANUP => 1)) or die $ff->error;
my $file = $ff->file;

while (-f "$dir/$file") {
    # change name, append a number, whatever...
    # $file = '...';
}

rename($where, "$dir/$file") or die $!;
```